# Storing JSON response in iOS error

Tags: xcode

I am making a call to an online php from my iOS app. In my output window I see the JSON Response with the data. But I need to store the NSString in my userdefaults but it is coming up NULL.

In this code the NSLog(@"JSON Response is %@", responseData); returns the json data just fine and I see the ipixid. But in the NSLog (@"ipixid is %@", ilixid); it returns ipixid is (null)

```
 NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@", strValue];
           NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
           NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ipixsocial.com/membership/getresult.php"];

           NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

           NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

           NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
           [request setURL:url1];
           [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
           [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
           [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
           [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
           [request setHTTPBody:postData];

           NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
           NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
           NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];


           if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
           {
               NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
               NSLog(@"JSON Response is %@", responseData);


               SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
               NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
               //   NSString *username = [(NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"email"]init];
               NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"uid"] integerValue];
               NSString* ipixid = [jsonData objectForKey:@"ipixid"];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ipixid forKey:@"ipixid"];


               NSLog (@"ipixid is %@", ipixid);
```

Comment: I'm confused.  Why not just store `responseData`?  You don't gain any advantage by parsing it into an `NSDictionary` and then just turning it back into a string.  If you only want the `uid` value just grab it with a REGEX.

Comment: Hey Max. I left out a bunch of code so that people didn't have to read through them all. There are about 15 responses that I need to store.

Comment: Ah, gotcha!  In that case yes it makes sense to get the dictionary working.  Is the dictionary itself null or just that one attribute/member/whatever?

Comment: That's the thing. The NSDictionary returns the values fine. I am totally lost why taking the objectforkey as an NSString and storing it returns NULL

Comment: So wait, is the object null, or just the string of the object, or just the stored string of the object?  In other words at what precise point does it become null?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ignore the "error" parameter you're passing to the parser. Also check that "jsonData" is not nil. I'm think that parsing is failing and because you're ignoring it and assuming jsonData is valid you're getting nil for  [jsonData objectForKey:@"ipixid"];

Comment: while I agree with you on all fronts, I think this would be more appropriate as a comment than an answer.  Frankly, unless someone encounters this question who specifically knows a lot about the particular JSON handling library that OP appears to be using, I don't think this question can really be answered.